# HTML Form to CSV with Multiple Rows of data

Tags: php, html, arrays, csv, foreach

Currently I have a form that I can fill out that generates a csv file with a single row of data with multiple columns. The columns are my select elements in my HTML Form and the selection is applied to the row below the header. I am needing the ability to duplicate the select elements which I have but I am not sure how to have that populate a second,third,fourth, etc row in the csv.

Expected Results

HEADER

Name, Email, Customer, Reseller, ActivationDate, Bandwidth, DeploymentType, Location, Type, OperatingSystem

ROW2

NameInput, EmailInput, CustomerInput, ResellerInput, ActivationDateInput, BandwidthInput, DeploymentTypeInput, LocationInput, TypeInput, OperatingSystemInput

ROW3

NameInput, EmailInput, CustomerInput, ResellerInput, ActivationDateInput, BandwidthInput, DeploymentTypeInput, LocationInput, TypeInput, OperatingSystemInput

ROW4

NameInput, EmailInput, CustomerInput, ResellerInput, ActivationDateInput, BandwidthInput, DeploymentTypeInput, LocationInput, TypeInput, OperatingSystemInput

ETC

```html
     <div id="serveroptions">
      <table id="server">
        <tr id="header">
          <td class="space">Deployment Location</td>
          <td>Server Type</td>
          <td>Server OS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="datainput">
          <td><select name="location[]" class="dropdown" id="location">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
              <option value="cavern">Cavern</option>
              <option value="greencloud">Green Cloud</option>
              <option value="onprem">On-Premise</option>
            </select><br></td>
          <td><select name="type[]" class="dropdown" id="type">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
              <option value="dc">Domain Controller</option>
              <option value="ca">CA</option>
              <option value="app">Application</option>
              <option value="sql">SQL</option>
              <option value="rds">RDS</option>
              <option value="exch">Exchange</option>
              <option value="util">Utility</option>
              <option value="other">Other</option>
              </select><br></td>
            <td><select name="os[]" class="dropdown" id="os">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
              <option value="windows">Windows</option>
              <option value="linux">Linux</option>
              <option value="ova">OVA</option>
              <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select><br></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
      <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add Row</button></br></br>
  </div>
  <p><label class="submitbutton"><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Form'></label></p>
</form>
</body>
```

```php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$data = array();

$data['name'] = $_POST["name"] ?? '';
$data['email'] = $_POST["email"] ?? '';
$data['customer'] = $_POST["customer"] ?? '';
$data['reseller'] = $_POST["reseller"] ?? '';
$data['activationdate'] = $_POST["activationdate"] ?? '';
$data['firewall'] = $_POST["bandwidth"] ?? '';
$data['deploytype'] = $_POST["deploytype"] ?? '';
$data['location'] = $_POST["location"] ?? '';
$data['type'] = $_POST["type"] ?? '';
$data['os'] = $_POST["os"] ?? '';


$errors = '';

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == 'type' || $key == 'os' || $key == 'deploytype'){ } //do nothing
  else {
  if (empty($value)) {
    //Field is empty && email
    if ($key == 'email') {
      if(!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid email address <br> ';
      }
    } else {
      //Field is empty && !email
      $errors .= $key. ' field is required. <br> ';
      }     
    }
  }
}
//if no errors carry on
if(empty($errors)){
  //# Title of the CSV
  $Content = "Name, Email, Customer, Reseller, ActivationDate, Bandwidth, DeploymentType, Location, Type, OperatingSystem\n";
  //set the data of the CSV
  // Added '' in each field as a delimiter
  $row = '';

  foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    # Appending value encased in quotes and trailing comma to row
    $row .= '"'. $value. '",';
  }
  //Remove trailing comma
  $row = mb_substr($row, 0, -1);

  $Content .= $row;
  //# set the file name and create CSV file
  $timestamp = date("Y-m-d_H-i-s"); //$timestamp takes the current time
  $myFile = $timestamp."_new-voice-deployment.csv"; // add timestamp to the file name
  $csv_handler = fopen ($myFile,'a'); //changed 'w' to 'a'
  if(fwrite ($csv_handler,$Content)){
    echo 'Form Submission Successfull';
  } else {
    echo "Form Submission UnSuccessfull";
  }
  fclose ($csv_handler);


} else {
  echo $errors;
}
}
```

Header to have select element options
Rows to have selections made in the form

Comment: can you share php also?

Comment: This is the php I am working off, I am using this for my other project and was hoping to edit this one to work with multiple rows.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand what is the desired result? it seems that on every submit you are creating new file with one long row of data. what is it that you want to change? do you want one file to add new rows to or do you want to break the long row?

Comment: You are correct, This script creates on submit a file with a single row of data. The desired result would be to create multiple rows of data in the same file. In the HTML I have an "Add Row" button that duplicates the elements so if you fill out the form without clicking this button it would be one row of data. However if you click "Add Row" and duplicate the elements then you would get a second row of data in the same file. Hope that helps

Comment: Here is what my array is spitting out to php, So in my form I dynamically duplicated the <tr id="datainput"> two times so I had a total of three rows of data to fill out. It is putting those selections into a child array but I am stumped on how my PHP script can parse the location, type, and os array and add those to separate rows in the csv file. [location] => Array ( [0] => cavern [1] => greencloud [2] => onprem ) [type] => Array ( [0] => util [1] => rds [2] => ca ) [os] => Array ( [0] => windows [1] => linux [2] => ova ) [submit] => Submit Form –

Comment: If you are adding timestamp each time you write to the file it will create new file. I'm not near computer so i will come again later and will look on it again.

Answer (score 0):

Continue the comments above, it seems you need to change just those two lines:

```
$myFile = $timestamp."_new-voice-deployment.csv"; // add timestamp to the file name
$csv_handler = fopen ($myFile,'w');
```

Into something like this:

```
$myFile = "data.csv"; // or any other filename...
$csv_handler = fopen ($myFile,'a'); // instead of w
```

Hope i finally understand..

---

Edit, i hope that (now) i finally understood your request (added comments on code):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  $data = array();
  $data['name'] = $_POST["name"] ?? '';
  $data['email'] = $_POST["email"] ?? '';
  $data['customer'] = $_POST["customer"] ?? '';
  $data['reseller'] = $_POST["reseller"] ?? '';
  $data['activationdate'] = $_POST["activationdate"] ?? '';
  $data['firewall'] = $_POST["bandwidth"] ?? '';
  $data['deploytype'] = $_POST["deploytype"] ?? '';
  $data['location'] = $_POST["location"] ?? '';
  $data['type'] = $_POST["type"] ?? '';
  $data['os'] = $_POST["os"] ?? '';
  $errors = '';
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'type' || $key == 'os' || $key == 'deploytype'){ } //do nothing
    else {
      if (empty($value)) { //Field is empty && email
        if ($key == 'email') {
          if(!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid email address <br> ';
          }
        } 
        else { //Field is empty && !email
          $errors .= $key. ' field is required. <br> ';
        }     
      }
    }
  }
  if(empty($errors)){  //if no errors carry on    
    $myFile = "data.csv"; // file name
    if(!file_exists($myFile)) { // if the file not exist make header
      $Content = "Name, Email, Customer, Reseller, ActivationDate, Bandwidth, DeploymentType, Location, Type, OperatingSystem\n";   // Title of  the CSV
      $csv_handler = fopen ($myFile,'a'); // changed 'w' to 'a'  
      fwrite ($csv_handler,$Content);
      fclose ($csv_handler);
    }
    $row = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value){
      if (is_array($value)) { $value = implode($value); } // check if the value is array - if so convert it to string.
      $row .= '"'. $value. '",';   // Appending value encased in quotes and trailing comma to row     
    }
    $row = mb_substr($row, 0, -1); //Remove trailing comma
    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d_H-i-s"); // optional - just to know when the line added to the file
    $row .= "," . $timestamp;
    $row .= "\n"; // add end of line so that new records would be under it
    $csv_handler = fopen ($myFile,'a'); // changed 'w' to 'a'
    if(fwrite ($csv_handler,$row)){ echo 'Form Submission Successfull'; } 
    else { echo "Form Submission UnSuccessfull"; }
    fclose ($csv_handler);
  } 
  else { echo $errors; }
}
?>


<form method="post" action="demo.php">
  <div id="serveroptions">
    <table id="server">
      <tr id="header">
        <td class="space">Deployment Location</td>
        <td>Server Type</td>
        <td>Server OS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="datainput">
        <td>
          <select name="location[]" class="dropdown" id="location">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="cavern">Cavern</option>
            <option value="greencloud">Green Cloud</option>
            <option value="onprem">On-Premise</option>
          </select>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="type[]" class="dropdown" id="type">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="dc">Domain Controller</option>
            <option value="ca">CA</option>
            <option value="app">Application</option>
            <option value="sql">SQL</option>
            <option value="rds">RDS</option>
            <option value="exch">Exchange</option>
            <option value="util">Utility</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="os[]" class="dropdown" id="os">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="windows">Windows</option>
            <option value="linux">Linux</option>
            <option value="ova">OVA</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
    <input type="text" name="customer" placeholder="customer" />
    <input type="text" name="reseller" placeholder="reseller" />
    <input type="text" name="activationdate" placeholder="activationdate" />
    <input type="text" name="bandwidth" placeholder="firewall" />
    <input type="text" name="deploytype" placeholder="deploytype" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add Row</button></br></br>

  <p><label class="submitbutton"><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Form'></label></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks A. Meshu, I will try this and see if that resolve's the issue. Will let you know the results.

Comment: This did not resolve. I posted more information in the original comments

Comment: The end result was a single row output and the location, type, and OperatingSytem in the .csv were populated with "Array","Array,"Array"

Here is the array that was sent to PHP

**[location] => Array ( [0] => cavern [1] => greencloud [2] => onprem ) [type] => Array ( [0] => dc [1] => app [2] => exch ) [os] => Array ( [0] => windows [1] => linux [2] => windows )**

Comment: This time the values just compiled in the same row but it did explode the values out it just strung them together. Here is what was output in the array and the csv is below in bold
`[location] => Array ( [0] => cavern [1] => greencloud [2] => onprem ) [type] => Array ( [0] => dc [1] => app [2] => sql ) [os] => Array ( [0] => windows [1] => linux [2] => ova ) [submit] => Submit Form `


**"caverngreencloudonprem","dcappsql","windowslinuxova",**

Comment: Strange. I tested this code (lamp + php v7.1)  and the output was new line each time with the selections and input values. I will look on it again later...

Comment: I tested with your code and your changes implemented to mine with the same results (wamp + php v7) as well

Comment: @quigleyvision So i double check it myself on another machine with wamp and php 7 and it's working as expected (different browsers too). Don't know what to say. Maybe open your notepad, copy-paste the entire code, save it on localhost/demo.php and lunch it with wamp.

Comment: I will compare code again but I am running your demo. The only thing I was unable to get working with your demo code and had to make a change to was the add row button did not function for me. How are you accomplishing this? Could you share your .csv so I could see your output?

Comment: Actually i haven't touched this cause i understood (i guess wrong) that this is not part of the problem... Have you manage to solve that? If not change the name attribute to an array one ("NAME[]") and clone the form. There is really good solution (with jquery) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714924/how-can-copy-div-including-many-scripts-onclick

Comment: @A .Meshu It is not part of the problem I was just curious how you were doing it in the demo since you said you were not having problems. If I copy the code you put in there I am unable to add a row to get multiple lines in the .csv file. In my code I am doing this with javascript but I was just unsure how you were getting multiple lines of data without adding a row.