# How can copy div including many scripts onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have web page includes many select options and description box 
I want when user press (Add New) button new div open with the same selection and description box exactly the same 
but my problem is the selection includes script code .. when I put it into function addrow() doesn't work

So how I can copy the same selection to work ad the same way when user press button (add new)
please help me

```
<html>
<select name="marklocation" id="type" style="width: 42%">
    <option value="">- Location -</option>
    <option value="Runway 17">Runway 17</option>
    <option value="Runway 35">Runway 35</option>
    <option value="Runway 18">Runway 18</option>
    <option value="Runway 36">Runway 36</option>
</select><br/>
<select name="markingtype" id="size" style="width: 42%">
    <option value="">-- Marking Type -- </option>
</select><br/>
<script>
$('#type').on('change', function(e) {
      let selector = $(this).val();
      $("#site > option").hide();
      var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "Runway 17") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='t'>- Marking Runway Types -</option><option value='Runway Designator Marking'>Runway Designator Marking </option><option value='Runway Centerline Marking'>Runway Centerline Marking</option><option value='Runway Threshold Marking'>Runway Threshold Marking</option><option value='Runway Side Strip Marking'>Runway Side Strip Marking</option><option value='Runway Aiming Point Marking'>Runway Aiming Point Marking</option><option value='Runway Touchdown Zone Marking'>Runway Touchdown Zone Marking</option><option value='Runway Displaced Threshold Marking'>Runway Displaced Threshold Marking</option><option value='Chevron Markings For Stopway'>Chevron Markings For Stopway</option>");
        } else if (val == "Runway 35") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='t'>- Marking Runway Types -</option><option value='Runway Designator Marking'>Runway Designator Marking </option><option value='Runway Centerline Marking'>Runway Centerline Marking</option><option value='Runway Threshold Marking'>Runway Threshold Marking</option><option value='Runway Side Strip Marking'>Runway Side Strip Marking</option><option value='Runway Aiming Point Marking'>Runway Aiming Point Marking</option><option value='Runway Touchdown Zone Marking'>Runway Touchdown Zone Marking</option><option value='Runway Displaced Threshold Marking'>Runway Displaced Threshold Marking</option><option value='Chevron Markings For Stopway'>Chevron Markings For Stopway</option>");
        } else if (val == "Runway 18") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='t'>- Marking Runway Types -</option><option value='Runway Designator Marking'>Runway Designator Marking </option><option value='Runway Centerline Marking'>Runway Centerline Marking</option><option value='Runway Threshold Marking'>Runway Threshold Marking</option><option value='Runway Side Strip Marking'>Runway Side Strip Marking</option><option value='Runway Aiming Point Marking'>Runway Aiming Point Marking</option><option value='Runway Touchdown Zone Marking'>Runway Touchdown Zone Marking</option><option value='Runway Displaced Threshold Marking'>Runway Displaced Threshold Marking</option><option value='Chevron Markings For Stopway'>Chevron Markings For Stopway</option>");
        } else if (val == "Runway 36") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='t'>- Marking Runway Types -</option><option value='Runway Designator Marking'>Runway Designator Marking </option><option value='Runway Centerline Marking'>Runway Centerline Marking</option><option value='Runway Threshold Marking'>Runway Threshold Marking</option><option value='Runway Side Strip Marking'>Runway Side Strip Marking</option><option value='Runway Aiming Point Marking'>Runway Aiming Point Marking</option><option value='Runway Touchdown Zone Marking'>Runway Touchdown Zone Marking</option><option value='Runway Displaced Threshold Marking'>Runway Displaced Threshold Marking</option><option value='Chevron Markings For Stopway'>Chevron Markings For Stopway</option>");
        }
});
</script>
<select name="tdmPassport" id="tdmPassport" style="width: 42%" class="auto-style2" onchange = "ShowHidDiv()">
                                        <option value="">- Marking Condition -</option>
                                        <option value="Good:Accepted Level"  style="background-color: #29BB29">Good</option>
                                        <option value="Medium:Maintenance Plan Level"  style="background-color: yellow">Medium</option>
                                        <option value="Poor:Corrective Action Level"  style="background-color: #FE4E4E">Poor</option>
                                    </select><br> 
<p class="auto-style3">Maintenance Plan:</p>  
                                   <textarea name="markingplan" id="planmark" style="width: 572px; height: 129px" ></textarea><br>

<input type="button" value="Add new" onclick="addRowr()"><br>
<div id="contentr">
  </div>
<script>
function addRowr () {
  document.querySelector('#contentr').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',
    `<div><input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removeRow(this)"><br>
    <select name="marklocation" id="type" style="width: 42%">
    <option value="">- Location -</option>
    <option value="Runway 17">Runway 17</option>
    <option value="Runway 35">Runway 35</option>
    <option value="Runway 18">Runway 18</option>
    <option value="Runway 36">Runway 36</option>
</select><br/>
<select name="markingtype" id="size" style="width: 42%">
    <option value="">-- Marking Type -- </option>
</select><br/>

   <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowr()"><br>
    </div>`      
  )
}
function removeRowr (inputr) {
  inputr.parentNode.remove()
}   
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: changing id's to class should be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to improve the code making it easier to read and maintain.

- Give input elements names square brackets so they will be posted as arrays on form submit
- Add a wrapper around each row for easy selecting
- Made a Javascript object to hold your option data. This way it's a lot cleaner and easier to maintain.
- Doing event handling with the delegate handler on the container div making it easier to maintain and possibility to add more handlers
- Rewritten the add row function so it clones the current row.
- Rewritten the remove function in jQuery style
- rewritten the change function to use the javascript object.

```js
var $contentr = $('#contentr');

//Clone this rowWrapper div, add remove button and append it to add another row
$contentr.on('click', '.addNewButton', function() {
  var $removeButton = $('<input>');
  $removeButton.attr('type', 'button');
  $removeButton.addClass('removeButton');
  $removeButton.val('Remove');

  $newRow = $(this).closest('.rowWrapper').clone();
  $newRow.append($removeButton).appendTo('#contentr');
  $('.rowWrapper').last().find('.marklocation').trigger('change');
});

//remove the current row if it's not the last
$contentr.on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
  $(this).closest('.rowWrapper').remove();
});

//Change the options of markingtype based on marklocation
$contentr.on('change', '.marklocation', function(event) {
  //$("#site > option").hide(); ??
  
  $this = $(event.target);
  var value = $this.val();
  
  //empty the select
  var $markingtype = $this.closest('.rowWrapper').find('.markingtype');
  $markingtype.empty();

  //filter the options which contain the runway number or default (-1)
  options.filter((opt) => {
    return opt.runways.includes(value) || opt.runways.includes('default');
  }).forEach((opt) => {
    //add the filtered options to the selectbox
    var $newOption = $('<option>');
    $newOption.val(opt.value);
    $newOption.text(opt.text);
    $markingtype.append($newOption);
  });
});

//data object dat contains text and value for the option elements belonging to runways
var options = [{
    text: '- Marking Runway Types -',
    value: 't',
    runways: ['default']
  }, {
    text: 'Runway Designator Marking',
    value: 'Runway Designator Marking',
    runways: ['Runway 35', 'Runway 18', 'Runway 36']
  },
  {
    text: 'Runway Centerline Marking',
    value: 'Runway Centerline Marking',
    runways: ['Runway 35', 'Runway 18', 'Runway 36']
  },
  {
    text: 'Runway Threshold Marking',
    value: 'Runway Side Strip Marking',
    runways: ['Runway 35', 'Runway 18', 'Runway 36']
  },
  {
    text: 'Runway Side Strip Marking',
    value: 'Runway Side Strip Marking',
    runways: ['Runway 35', 'Runway 18', 'Runway 36']
  },
  {
    text: 'Runway Aiming Point Marking',
    value: 'Runway Aiming Point Marking',
    runways: ['Runway 35', 'Runway 18', 'Runway 36']
  },
  {
    text: 'Runway Touchdown Zone Marking',
    value: 'Runway Touchdown Zone Marking',
    runways: ['Runway 35', 'Runway 18', 'Runway 36']
  },
  {
    text: 'Runway Displaced Threshold Marking',
    value: 'Runway Displaced Threshold Marking',
    runways: ['Runway 35', 'Runway 18', 'Runway 36']
  },
  {
    text: 'Chevron Markings For Stopway',
    value: 'Chevron Markings For Stopway',
    runways: ['Runway 35', 'Runway 18', 'Runway 36']
  },
];
```

```css
.rowWrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contentr">
  <div class="rowWrapper">
    <select class="marklocation" name="marklocation[]" style="width: 42%">
      <option value="">- Location -</option>
      <option value="Runway 17">Runway 17</option>
      <option value="Runway 35">Runway 35</option>
      <option value="Runway 18">Runway 18</option>
      <option value="Runway 36">Runway 36</option>
    </select><br/>
    <select class="markingtype" name="markingtype[]" style="width: 42%">
      <option value="">-- Marking Type -- </option>
    </select><br/>

    <select class="tdmPassport" name="tdmPassport[]" style="width: 42%" class="auto-style2">
      <option value="">- Marking Condition -</option>
      <option value="Good:Accepted Level" style="background-color: #29BB29">Good</option>
      <option value="Medium:Maintenance Plan Level" style="background-color: yellow">Medium</option>
      <option value="Poor:Corrective Action Level" style="background-color: #FE4E4E">Poor</option>
    </select><br>
    <p class="auto-style3">Maintenance Plan:</p>
    <textarea class="markingplan" name="markingplan[]" style="width: 572px; height: 129px"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input class="addNewButton" type="button" value="Add new"><br>
  </div>
</div>
```